# Differences of embedded and field

Tags: go, struct

There are embedded struct `Struct1` and a struct `Struct2` defined as field. Both `fmt.Printf()` are same results while there is a difference for the initialization. I confused about this. I'm sorry.

1. What differences are these between `Struct1` and `Struct2`?
2. Which should be used under what situation?

#### Script

```
type sample1 struct {
    Data string
}

type sample2 struct {
    Data string
}

type Struct1 struct {
    *sample1
    *sample2
}

type Struct2 struct {
    Sample1 sample1
    Sample2 sample2
}

func main() {
    s1 := &Struct1{
        &sample1{},
        &sample2{},
    }
    s1.sample1.Data = "s1 sample1 data"
    s1.sample2.Data = "s1 sample2 data"

    s2 := &Struct2{}
    s2.Sample1.Data = "s2 sample1 data"
    s2.Sample2.Data = "s2 sample2 data"

    fmt.Printf("%s, %s\n", s1.sample1.Data, s1.sample2.Data)
    fmt.Printf("%s, %s\n", s2.Sample1.Data, s2.Sample2.Data)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/gUy6gwVJDP

Thank you so much for your time and advices. And I'm sorry for my immature question.

Comment: "while there is a difference for the initialization" --- you can initialise them the same way: `s2 := &Struct2{
  sample1{"foo"},
  sample2{"bar"}
 }`

Comment: @zerkms I appreciate for your advice. For ``s1``, pointer has to be used like ``s1 := &Struct1{&sample1{"foo"}, &sample2{"bar"}}``. ``s1 := &Struct1{sample1{"foo"}, sample2{"bar"}}`` occurs an error. So I thought those are difference.

Comment: Because for the first one those should be pointers (you declared it so): `&sample1` and `&sample2`. It's totally not a "difference".

Comment: @zerkms This is new information for me. Now I could know that Struct1 and Struct2 are the same. Are there suitable situations for those?

Comment: For me - embedding is a design tool. If a type relates to another type via an "is a" relation, then you embed it (but only if it's necessary). Otherwise you do not. So by default - prefer to never embed.

Comment: @zerkms I appreciate for your great advices. I could understand this problem. I would like to accept this as a solved question. Can you write your answer? Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: May I advice you to acquire and read ["The Go Programming language" book](http://www.gopl.io/)? It is IMHO of astonishing quality in delivering the material in gentle and gradual way, and at the same time it deals with all the gory details--including the embedding. (I'm not affiliated with neither the authors nor the sellers.)

Comment: @kostix Thank you for your advices. I have never known the Book you showed. I always have seen at Google, https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1 and https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html I would like to also consider such books.

Comment: The tour is a very good starting point, and Effective Go is a very good material, but [there are plenty of books on Go as well](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Books) (some of them are even free; look for the book by Caleb Doxsey for example). Of those I read, the one I recommended, is unparalleled in the way it presents the material. The only problem one may have with it is that it assumes prior knowledge or a C-like language; complete beginners might get lost in it.

Comment: @kostix Thank you so much for your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As about second question, personally I mostly use embedding to promote methods

```
//having
type Doer interface{
    Do()
}
func DoWith(d Doer){}
func (s sample1)Do(){} //implemented
type Struct1 struct {
    sample1
}
type Struct2 struct {
    Sample1 sample1
}
var s1 Struct1
var s2 Struct2
//you can call
DoWith(s1) //method promoted so interface satisfied
//but cannot
DoWith(s2)
```

and to decode JSON,

```
//having
type Sample1 struct {
    Data string `json:"data"`
}
type Sample2 struct {
    Number int `json:"number"`
}
//you can easy and handy compose
type Struct1 struct {
    Sample1
    Sample2
}
var s1 Struct1
json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"data": "foo", "number": 5}`), &s1)
fmt.Println(s1.Data, s1.Number) //print foo 5
```

Comment: Thank you for your advices and samples. These samples are very helpful for me. I would like to solve my question with your answer. Thank you again.